# Degree of sequence  of mappings

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

If $f_n$ is a sequence of smooth orientation preserning  mappings of degree one between open annuli $A(1,r):=\{x: 1< |x| < r \}$ and $A(1,r_n)$, $r>1$ and $r_n>1$, on the Euclidean space $\mathbf{R}^d$,  converging (in compacts of $A(1,r)$ together with the derivatives) to a smooth mapping $f$. What can be said about the degree of $f$?

Of course all the mappings $f_n$ are sirjective and for einstance map the inner (outer) boundary onto inner (outer) boundary

Comment: What does your notation $A(1,r)$ mean? Do you mean the set of points in $R^d$ of norm $\ge 1$ and $\le r$?

Comment: $A(r,1)$ is the set of points of norm $>1 $ and $<r$.


Comment: Next question: without further restrictions, the degree is not well-defined. For instance, take $r=2$, $r_n=3$ for all $n$, and $f_n : A(1,2) \to A(1,3)$ to be the inclusion map, so $f_n$ converges to the inclusion map. Over all points of $A(1,3)$ of norm $<2$ the degree is $1$, and over all points of norm between $2$ and $3$ the degree is zero, so the degree of the limit is not well-defined. Do you have any further restrictions in mind to avoid examples like this?

Comment: Of course all the mappings $f_n$ are sirjective and for einstance map the inner (outer) boundary onto inner (outer) boundary.  

Comment: Degree of the limit is 1: Just stretch all target annuli to be the same. The new maps still converge and are eventually homotopic to limit rel. boundary. 

Comment: Thank you very much. I was not sure that the degree of the limiting function is one, because the sequence $r_n$ can tend to $1$ and therefore the limiting function is a singular mapping, for example the mapping $f(x)=x/|x|$?

Comment: @Marijan: You have to exclude the case $r= 1$ since degree makes sense only for maps between manifolds of the same dimension. (Of course, you can declare degree to be zero if dimensions are different, but then you already know that $deg(f)=0$.) 